# Bind Kendo pie chart with Datasource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to use a pie chart to display statistics. Data is within my table and i get it this way:

```
public class StatisticsAccess
{
    public static object getTypesForStatistics()
    {
        var dbo = new UsersContext();
        var all = (from a in dbo.Note
                      select a).ToList();
        var results = all.GroupBy(item => item.language.lang)
                         .Select(g => new
                         {
                             language = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Count()
                         });
        return (results.ToList());

    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public class StatisticsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Statistics/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();      
    }

    public void displayChart()
    {
        var results = Json(DAL.StatisticsAccess.getTypesForStatistics()); 
    }

}
```

View:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart()
    .Name("chart")
            .Title(title => title
                .Text("Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012")
                .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
        .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Column("Count").CategoryField("language");
            })


            .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("displayChart", "Statistics")))
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0}%")
    )


)
```

There are no syntax errors in my view but my chart simply appears empty when i load the page.

Can anyone explain me the syntax i shoud follow to fix this error ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two major issues with your code.

You've defined a column chart, this should be a pie chart:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyModel>()
    .Name("chart")
    .Title(title => title
        .Text("Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012")
        .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
    .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
    .Series(series => {
        series.Pie(model => model.language, model => model.Count);
    })
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("displayChart", "Statistics")))
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0}%")
    )
)
```

Your action returns void, instead of an `ActionResult`:

```
public class StatisticsController : Controller
{    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult displayChart()
    {
        var results = DAL.StatisticsAccess.getTypesForStatistics();
        return Json(results);
    }
}
```

In addition you might want to do this:

Create a view model:

```
public class PieModel {
    public string Language { get;set; }
    public int Count { get;set; }
}
```

Add the model to your chart.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<PieModel>() {
    ...
```

Change your query:

```
public IEnumerable<PieModel> getTypesForStatistics()
{
    var dbo = new UsersContext();
    var all = (from a in dbo.Note
                      select a).ToList();
    var results = all.GroupBy(item => item.language.lang)
                         .Select(g => new PieModel
                         {
                             Language = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Count()
                         });
    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but the chart still appears empty :(